# Error Amount when launching a process in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When I launch my sub I have this amount bellow for the FR0G0 store (FR0G0 = the store's id):
[image]

What I can't explain it's when I launch for the 3rd times the process, I have the correct amount, as below:
[image]

My data source is from the sheet "DETAIL MAG" - I need for each store id (in orange) to calculte the total amount (in blue) and paste the result in the "IML" sheet, in column G:
[image]

Here my code :

```
Sub Iml_FR0G0()

    Dim FR0G0 As Range
    Dim SUM_FR0G0 As Double
    Dim DernLigne As Double
    
    DernLigne = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last row
    Set FR0G0 = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'setting whole range of data
    Sheets("DETAIL MAG").AutoFilterMode = False 'turning off all filters
    FR0G0.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="FR0G0" 'filtering data
    SUM_FR0G0 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("R1:R" & DernLigne).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) 'summing filtered data
    
    Sheets("IML").Select
    DernLigne = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("G" & DernLigne).Value = SUM_FR0G0
```

Do you have any ideas why it happens?
I do the same process for 6 different stores.

Comment: `.End(xlUp).Row + 1` is not the last row, it's the second to last. The subsequent `.CurrentRegion` undoes it anyway and selects the current region instead (which in the general case is very much not "from first row to last"). Then you sum something, it's unclear whether the column being summed is even on the screenshot, as you have cropped the column headers. So it's absolutely unclear what behaviour you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: Hi @GSerg, thank you for your answer and sorry if it was unclear. I just edit the post

Comment: So what you actually want is a `SUMIF` formula in G?

Comment: Yes, in the IML sheet, column G. 
When I call the sub for the 1st time, the total amount is incorrect (5 700,25). What I don't understand is when I call a second time I have the correct amount (6 454,41)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to specify the sheet before using range.
Also, you can use sumif function instead of using filter.

```
Sub Iml_FR0G0()
Dim FR0G0 As Range
Dim SUM_FR0G0 As Double
Dim DernLigne As Double
DernLigne = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last row
Set FR0G0 = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'setting whole range of data
Sheets("DETAIL MAG").AutoFilterMode = False 'turning off all filters
SUM_FR0G0 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(FR0G0.Range(FR0G0.Cells(1, 12), FR0G0.Cells(DernLigne, 12)), "FR0G0", FR0G0.Range(FR0G0.Cells(1, 18), FR0G0.Cells(DernLigne, 18)))
Sheets("IML").Activate
DernLigne = Sheets("IML").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("IML").Range("G" & DernLigne).Value = SUM_FR0G0
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `FR0G0.Range(FR0G0.Cells(1, 12), FR0G0.Cells(DernLigne, 12)` you can write `FR0G0.Columns(12)`

Comment: Hi @Script Developer, thanks for your help. I still  have the incorrect amount  (5700,25 instead of 6 454,41)